# jboss-4.0.3SP1 LinkageError loader constraint violation

Tags: jakarta-ee

java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/jboss/web/tomcat/tc5/WebAppClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "xyz/xyz/xyz/xyz/GateAuthorisationManagerRemote"
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:1815)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:869)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1322)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1201)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:1935)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getPrivateMethod(ObjectStreamClass.java:1382)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$1700(ObjectStreamClass.java:52)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:438)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.(ObjectStreamClass.java:413)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:310)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:507)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1539)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1493)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1732)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
    at java.rmi.MarshalledObject.get(MarshalledObject.java:142)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.MarshalledValuePair.get(MarshalledValuePair.java:72)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:652)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:587)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at yes.util.Lookup.multiSiteLookup(Lookup.java:264)
    at yes.util.Lookup.getEJB(Lookup.java:313)
    at yes.util.Lookup.getEJB(Lookup.java:342)
    at 
....
..
..

I was googling a lot and didn't found any anwer that could solve my problem.
I checked that the class WebAppClassLoader is in two jars: catalina.jar and tomcat55-service.jar.
I think that it's the problem, but i cannot remove any of this jars because app won't start at all.
In WEB-INF/lib i don't have any jars.
Can anybody help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This Exception generally caught whenever we are using EJB,**

The Solution of the above problem is that this particular (GateAuthorisationManagerRemote) class remove from multiple jar and war .
class file  exist in multiple jar or war file, so we have to remove multiple existence of this classes and only keep one existence of this class .